# Sync AWS Secrets manager with Kubernetes secrets on local not working when using minikube and localstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-secrets-manager, kubernetes-secrets, csi-driver

I am trying to configure AWS secrets with my kubernetes cluster in such a way that I can expose secrets as environment variable in my deployment file

OS: Mac
I am using minikube for local testing
For AWS I am using localstack

##### secrets manager I have created a secret

[image]

I have created this yaml file

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: airflow-deployment-aws-secrets-dev
spec:
  provider: aws
  secretObjects:       # [OPTIONAL] SecretObject defines the desired state of synced K8s secret objects
  - data:
    - key: AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR                           # data field to populate
      objectName: AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR                        # name of the mounted content to sync. this could be the object 
    secretName: airflow-environment                    # name of the Kubernetes Secret object
    type: Opaque    

  parameters:
    objects: |
        - objectName: "AirflowSecretDev"
          objectType: "secretsmanager"
    region: "us-west-1"
    endpoint-url: "http://host.docker.internal:4566"
```

In my deployment file I have used

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: airflow-scheduler
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: airflow-scheduler
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: airflow-scheduler
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: airflow-scheduler
          image: airflow-testing-image-1:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never 
          command: ["/bin/bash", "-c",  "airflow db check-migrations -t 0 || airflow db upgrade || true; airflow scheduler"]
          env:
            - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: airflow-environment
                  key: AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR
```

But this whole is not working and getting following error

[image]

#### kubernetes logs for  csi drivers

[image]

Please let me know what am I doing wrong in this .